# jquery: give user a "no data" message rather than printing an empty graph

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, charts

I have a code for drawing a chart based on MySQL data. However, I want to improve this code in the following way - if MySQL result set is empty, then I want to display a text message (e.g. 'No input data') instead of a chart.

I'm searching for a way to update `mainFunc.php` so that it could read outputs of `mainChart.php` and display a chart or a text message. How to do this in a simplest way?

**myChart.php**

```
include_once '../include/DatabaseConnector.php';    
$query1="SELECT xxx, yyy FROM mySQLTable;";
$result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query1);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result1); 
if ($num_results > 0){ 
// do something
echo 1;
}
else echo 0;
```

**mainFunc.php**

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="chart">
    <img src="charts/myChart.php">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think PHP is in the business of drawing vectors.

Comment: There is no problem with drawing a chart - I'm using jpGraph that returns an image. Now I want to improve my code and avoid drawing charts for cases when myFunc returns 0. This should be simple to do, but I'm just newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky part about jpgraph is that it returns an image file, so you can't just echo some text inside the jpgraph file. You have two options:

1. Detect the lack of results outside of mygraph.php and avoid calling mygraph.php in the first place.
2. Use JPgraph's facilities for writing (drawing) text to make an image that says "no results found."

#### Detect no results and skip the graph

To do #1, just pull your query code out of mygraph.php (put it in a different include file, if you want). After the query, count the results. If there are zero, return some text and write it to the page. If there are results, return an img tag like you have now, and write that to the page.

Now, since the query is no longer being done inside mygraph.php, how do you get it the data to graph? There easiest way is just to pass it in the query string, and mygraph.php can read it from `$_GET`. Check out the [documentation on passing data to jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch13s03.html) for more options.

#### Draw a "no data" message

[Here's some code](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/example_src/textpalignex1.html) from the jpgraph website that shows you how to create an image consisting of a text message. I've used servers that don't have truetype support installed, which can make jpgraph's text look a little wonky, so make sure it appears satisfactory on your production server.

Comment: Nice solution. I like "Draw a "no data" message"